# python/django no module named yelp

Tags: python, django, api

I downloaded the yelp github for python and there's three files inside the python folder. I placed these three folders inside a folder named `yelp` which lays inside `mysite`. (I'm following django's creating first app documentation). This `mysite` folder has the `polls` folder as well.

When I added yelp into the `settings.py` INSTALLED_APPS, why do I still get `no module named yelp` if I tried to do `python manage.py runserver`?

Please help, I'm still trying to learn how python works, what to do when you bring in a new .py file..?

thank you!

Comment: Which github project are you referring to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to have an `__init__.py` inside both the mysite and yelp directories, and you need to import it as `mysite.yelp`.

Older versions of python will allow implicit relative imports, but in general there should be one root package that's importable, and anything inside of it should be imported with the full name. And the way django works, your whole site needs to be the importable package.

If there's an existing project available from github, though, it's usually a better idea to install the whole thing on your system instead of copying it into your project. That way if there are updates, you can keep up with what's new and update to the latest.

Comment: Sorry for this question (I'm new at this): can you explain as to what you mean importable package? Also, can you explain how I would "import" it as mysite.yelp? Should I just copy the `__init__.py into the `yelp` folder? Do I need to do this all the time if I bring in new folders? Thank you

Comment: First, have a look at http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#packages. The `__init__.py` is usually just an empty file. It just needs to be there to signal to python that the dir it's in is a package, and it sort of "grafts" packages together. What I meant by "importable" is that mysite needs to be not just a directory but a package with an `__init__.py`, and you need to make sure that if you put `import mysite` in your manage.py, you don't get `ImportError: No module named mysite`.

Comment: And as far as importing it, you either need to do `from mysite import yelp` and refer to it as `yelp`, or better `import mysite.yelp` and refer to it as `mysite.yelp`. If you have a mysite/yelp/foo.py you want to use inside of it, you could `import mysite.yelp.foo` or do `from mysite.yelp import foo`.

Comment: awww thank you thank you! one last question... How is the convention of directories? Should I have put the files inside `polls` directory? Or should I put the `yelp` folder inside the `polls` directory? From your experience what do you think I should do in this case, and for future cases (if I need to bring in a new .py file). Since I'm starting new, I don't want to make bad habits.

Comment: I would say to keep it fairly fluid, but no sense nesting code deeper than it needs to be. Lean _slightly_ towards dumping code in one long .py file and dumping files in the top-level dir to begin with, and just start to notice tightly interrelated areas of the code and demote them to separate files and dirs. Usually files nested under the same dir will be importing each other (without any import cycles, of course) and not importing much if any code outside that dir.